# Disable a specific key without downloading software?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

One of the F keys on a laptop keyboard is broken and causing problems. Removing the key itself does little to resolve the issue. Replacing the keyboard or taking it in to the shop isn't an option right now and it needs to be in working order soon. Leaving the key enabled is causing issues with the touch pad as the mouse won't move while it's acting up and the computer thinks the key is being pressed, but the key is literally never used so it can be disabled without causing any problems. How can I completely disable the broken key without downloading any software?

Comment: While you can remap keys, of the system thinks the key is being pressed, simply remapping it is not going to solve any problems.

Answer (score 0):

While you can remap keys in Windows without any extra software, your computer thinks the key is being pressed constantly and that cannot be ignored by the system. The best you would get is the computer thinking a different key is being pressed constantly.

The root problem is a hardware problem, and you cannot solve most hardware problems using software.

The good news is you don't have to buy software to fix you problem, the bad news is you have to pay hardware support.

Comment: That doesn't really answer to question, which is how to disable the key at a software level without downloading anything. If you had included instruction on how to remap the key so it didn't register as anything, how to zero it out, this might be a good answer.

Comment: It may not be answer you wish there was, but the issue is that your root problem is not a software problem and so cannot be resolved or mitigated by software. The touchpad isn't working because of hardware-level interrupts sent from the keyboard. Any changes to software impact after the hardware and so will not fix your issue of the touchpad not working due to the ghost key presses.

Comment: While I can't say whether an appropriate solution exists that still also fits within the OP's scopage, I have to say this answer isn't very appropriate, or even factual.  For example, with AHK you not only can rebind keys, you can even specify the key state (e.g., {LCtrl Down}, {LCtrl Up}).  The root problem may *likely* be a hardware problem, but you follow with an overtly generalized statement that hasn't actually been properly deduced,  Finally, whether the news is good or bad really isn't up to you to say but in either case the OP certainly does **not** "have to pay for hardware support".

Comment: @Arctiic much of that is a matter of opinion, and you're welcome to post your own answer that you feel is more accurate based on your own assumptions. The more answers the better for SU and for Demon here. If the key strokes are not system-interrupt level, and AHK can interfere with them, that will be great news for OP.

Comment: @music2myear That's *exactly* one of the points I was alluding to: it **shouldn't** be a matter of [opinion](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), nor would I feel comfortable with posting an answer that wasn't fully substantiated first.  Unless I'm interpreting SE's guidance incorrectly?  I've worked in the Food Safety sector for 10+ years, so this could admittedly be one of those times my occupational paradigms are predisposing my view.